# Group PHP ODBC results with common dataset?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I'm using PHP to connect to and display data from an ODBC MS Access database. I'm able to display the necessary data with a select statement, but I'm failing to learn how to group this data based on another dataset.

Here is my code:

```
<?
$handle = odbc_connect("Potter","","");
$results = odbc_exec($handle, "SELECT DISTINCT prodModelNo, prodSubType, prodCAD FROM product WHERE prodType NOT LIKE 'Plus' AND prodType = 'Fire' AND prodCAD LIKE '%CAD Drawing%' GROUP BY prodSubType");

        // Results List
        odbc_fetch_row($results, 0);
        while(odbc_fetch_row($results)){
            $cadString1     = odbc_result($results, "prodCAD");
            $cadString2     = str_replace('<img src=images/i_drawing.gif> <a href=fire/', '', $cadString1);
            $cadURL         = str_replace(' target=_blank>CAD Drawing (zip format)</a>', '', $cadString2);
            echo "<div id='file'><div id='filelink'><ul><li><a href='$cadURL'><img src='../images/download.png'/> Download</a> (zip format)</li></ul></div>";
            echo odbc_result($results, "prodModelNo");
            echo "<div class='clear'></div></div>";
        }
?>
```

This outputs a list of accurate data. What I'd like to do is group results that share a common category and have that category name displayed between each group. The column for category names in the database is called prodSubType.

How would I get this to display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `GROUP BY prodSubType` use `ORDER BY prodSubType` - so you can grab all items.

Then, in your code, have a BEFORE and AFTER variable to output the header differences (I'm not good at explaining this). See example (untested):

```
<?php
$handle = odbc_connect("Potter","","");
$results = odbc_exec($handle, "SELECT DISTINCT prodModelNo, prodSubType, prodCAD FROM product WHERE prodType NOT LIKE 'Plus' AND prodType = 'Fire' AND prodCAD LIKE '%CAD Drawing%' ORDER BY prodSubType ASC");

// Results List
odbc_fetch_row($results, 0);
$oldHeader = "";
while(odbc_fetch_row($results)){
  $header = odbc_result($results, "prodSubType");
  if($header != $oldHeader) {
    $oldHeader = $header;
    echo "<h1>$header</h1>";
  }
  $cadString1     = odbc_result($results, "prodCAD");
  $cadString2     = str_replace('<img src=images/i_drawing.gif> <a href=fire/', '', $cadString1);
  $cadURL         = str_replace(' target=_blank>CAD Drawing (zip format)</a>', '', $cadString2);
  echo "<div id='file'><div id='filelink'><ul><li><a href='$cadURL'><img src='../images/download.png'/> Download</a> (zip format)</li></ul></div>";
  echo odbc_result($results, "prodModelNo");
  echo "<div class='clear'></div></div>";
}
?>
```